# Why other files are added when Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll is referenced in a project?

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm working on a windows form application which Visual Studio 2008.

Recently I added to my project the "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll". However, when I looked in the bin folder, after build the project, the following files have been added beyond the dll:

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xml

Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll

Office.dll

office.xml

My team asked me why these files were added, an I not knew how answer. Someone have a nice explanation for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the ["Primary Interop Assemblies"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and are required:

> Some assemblies are added to a project automatically when an assembly that references them is added. For example, references to the Office.dll and Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll assemblies are added automatically when you add a reference to the Word, Excel, Outlook, Microsoft Forms, or Graph assemblies.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer.

I move the .exe file to other machine with no visual studio installed, only Microsoft Office and .NET Framework 2.0. Then I removed other files and leave only "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll". The application works great.

Do you recommends leave like this? Or should I copy the other files that have been added?

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess they are installed in the GAC when you install Office. You won't need them then.